# How to mock for each loop properly using Mockito?

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I would like to test my method and I need to mock the vector of Items and Rows to go through each of them.

I prepared the result vector that I would like to get always when I call getRows() from Item class (within the test).

The problem is that the result of getRows method in test is always empty so it means that doReturn statement is not working correctly here.

Am I wrong with something?

```
class MyServiceTest {
@Mock
private Item mockedItem;

@Mock
private Row mockedRow;

@InjectMocks
@Spy
private MyService myService;

@Test
public void testMyMethod() {
    Vector<Row> rows = new Vector<Row>();
    Row row = new Row();
    rows.add(row);

    doReturn(rows).when(mockedItem).getRows();

    ...
    //some code to test the service

    }
}

class MyService {
    protected SomeObject myMethod(Vector<Item> items) {     
        for(Item item : items) {
            for(Row row : item.getRows()) {
               //cannot get here while debugging the test

               //some code
            }
        }
    ...
    }
}
class Item {
...
    public Vector<Row> getRows(){
       //return some vector of rows
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the test code where `mockedItem` is used? I'd rather suspect that it isn't being in the mocked service, and not that `doReturn` isn't working.

Comment: Can you also show the code of class `Row`.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly, but It is not used anywhere. After doReturn I just call the service and then do asserts.

Comment: @StefanBirkner There is nothing special there - it just creates the list with some values. Anyway, I was expecting that doReturn does not call the method getRows at all and should just always return the same vector. Am I wrong?

Comment: where is myMethod() called? You need to show more of the MyService class. Because I suspect you arent correctly injecting the mock Item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@InjectMock` is useless as the mocked vector is a parameter of the tested method, not a field of the class under test.
So you need to inject nothing.

What you need to do is creating a `Vector` of Item  where each element is a mock with the expected behavior for `getRows()` : returning stubbed rows.

Here is a sample code :

```
// create stubbed rows
Vector<Row> rows = new Vector<Row>();
Row row = new Row();
rows.add(row);

// mock items Vector
Vector<Item> items = new Vector<>();
for (...){ // nb element to create
  Item mockedItem = Mockito.mock(Item.class);
  doReturn(rows).when(mockedItem).getRows();
  items.add(mockedItem);
}
```

Then invoke your tested method by passing the vector:

```
new MyService().myMethod(items);
```

Note that Vector is an old and flawed Collection.
User rather `List` and `ArrayList` as implementation if you don't need to handle race conditions.